# What's the best way to parse an XML dateTime in Java?

Tags: java, xml

What's the best way to parse an XML dateTime in Java? Legal dateTime values include 2002-10-10T12:00:00-05:00 AND 2002-10-10T17:00:00Z

Is there a good open source library I can use, or should I roll my own using SimpleDateFormat or similar?

Answer (score 74):

There's also [javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter#parseDateTime(String xsdDateTime)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html#parseDateTime%28java.lang.String%29), which comes as part of the JDK.

Comment: I found this the easiest way without having to add in another library.  Thanks!

Comment: This is good, but it allows 'dateTime' values without timestamps, and 'dateTimeStamp' values with timestamps. Is there any way to require one or the other?

Comment: Stops working out of the box once you upgrade to java 11 because the package javax.xml.bind has been removed from JDK/JRE in 11.

Answer (score 41):

I think you want [`ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeNoMillis()`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/format/ISODateTimeFormat.html#dateTimeNoMillis()) from [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net). In general 
 I would *strongly* urge you to stay away from the built-in Date/Calendar classes in Java. Joda Time is much better designed, favours immutability (in particular the formatters are immutable and thread-safe) and is the basis for the new date/time API in Java 7.

Sample code:

```
import org.joda.time.*;
import org.joda.time.format.*;

class Test
{   
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        parse("2002-10-10T12:00:00-05:00");
        parse("2002-10-10T17:00:00Z");
    }

    private static final DateTimeFormatter XML_DATE_TIME_FORMAT =
        ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeNoMillis();

    private static final DateTimeFormatter CHECKING_FORMAT =
        ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime().withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC);

    static void parse(String text)
    {
        System.out.println("Parsing: " + text);
        DateTime dt = XML_DATE_TIME_FORMAT.parseDateTime(text);
        System.out.println("Parsed to: " + CHECKING_FORMAT.print(dt));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Parsing: 2002-10-10T12:00:00-05:00
Parsed to: 2002-10-10T17:00:00.000Z
Parsing: 2002-10-10T17:00:00Z
Parsed to: 2002-10-10T17:00:00.000Z
```

(Note that in the output both end up as the same UTC time. The output formatted uses UTC because we asked it to with the `withZone` call.)

Comment: This was very helpful! In order to maintain the original timezone offset, I used DateTimeFormatter 
`XML_DATE_TIME_FORMAT = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeNoMillis().withOffsetParsed()`

Answer (score 8):

## tl;dr

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2002-10-10T17:00:00Z" );
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( "2002-10-10T12:00:00-05:00" );
```

## Details

The other Answers are correct but now outdated. They use troublesome old classes now supplanted by the java.time framework.

No such thing as an “XML dateTime”. [XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) does not define any data type beyond text.

## Using java.time

The input string happens to comply with [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) standard formatting. So no need to specify a formatting pattern as the java.time classes use ISO 8601 by default when parsing/generating strings.

### `Instant`

The second input string ends in a `Z`, short for `Zulu`, and means [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).

The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond).

```
String input = "2002-10-10T17:00:00Z":
Instant instant = Instant.parse( input );
```

### `OffsetDateTime`

The first input string includes an offset-from-UTC, so we parse as an `OffsetDateTime`.

```
String input = "2002-10-10T12:00:00-05:00" ;
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( input );
```

### `ZonedDateTime`

If you have a specific time zone in mind, rather than a mere offset-from-UTC, apply that.

Use a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) in format of `continent/region`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviations that are not true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Cancun" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = odt.atZone( zoneId );
```

[image]

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the old troublesome date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `.Calendar`, & `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`.

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations.

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to [Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)) in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as `Interval`, `YearWeek`, `YearQuarter`, and more.

Comment: "No such thing as an 'XML dateTime'. XML does not define any data type beyond text." While this is true, what this question is almost certainly asking about is `xsd:dateTime`, aka an "XML Schema dateTime". https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dateTime

Answer (score 6):

StaxMan is absolutely correct.  In order to use SimpleDateFormat, you need to turn off lax parsing in each SimpleDateFormat and iterate over several SimpleDateFormat formats until you find the one that parses the date without throwing an exception.  If you leave lax parsing on, you are prone to get a match when you didn't really want one, and the [lexical space of XSD:DateTime](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dateTime) leaves some flexibility in format that SimpleDateFormat can't handle in a single expression.

XML Schema 1.0 does indeed use ISO 8601, which Joda Time, as suggested by Jon Skeet, implements so that is a valid option.

If you want to keep it all in the native Java packages, you can also use [XMLGregorianCalendar](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/datatype/XMLGregorianCalendar.html) in conjunction with [DatatypeFactory](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/datatype/DatatypeFactory.html) to parse and create XSD:Datetime strings.

See DatatypeFactory.newXMLGregorianCalendar and XMLGregorianCalendar.toXMLFormat

Answer (score 2):

See [Parse and format dateTime values](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/XML/ParseandformatxsdateTimevalues.htm), although:
-It takes "GMT" as the default timezone
-It does not complain if there are trailing non-parseable parts
-Does not take into account that TimeZone defaults to "GMT" on wrong "GMT+xxxx"

Answer (score 1):

http://xmlbeans.apache.org/samples/DateTime.html

There is XmlDateTime class. Just do XMLDateTime.stringToDate(xmlDateTime).

Answer (score 1):

In XML Beans v2 it would be `XmlDateTime.Factory.parse(dateTimeString)`, but this is awkward because it expects an element with start and end tags like `<mytime>2011-10-20T15:07:14.112-07:00</mytime>`

An easier approach is to call `(new org.apache.xmlbeans.GDate(dateTimeString)).getDate()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [newXMLGregorianCalendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/datatype/DatatypeFactory.html#newXMLGregorianCalendar%28java.lang.String%29) in `javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory`, which gives you detailed control, including detecting whether the timezone was specified or not.

Comment: Where can one find an implementation of `javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory`?  The only one I'm finding is in xerces2... I thought xerces2 was out of date... (I'm coming back to Java after a while)

Comment: You don't need to find one -- use [DatatypeFactory.newInstance()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/datatype/DatatypeFactory.html#newInstance()) and your JVM will search for one which was installed with Java.

Comment: Right--I should have removed my question once I figured that out.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, XML processing packages that are schema-aware (or to be used as basis for things that are) should provide accessors for typed content. I know of one (http://woodstox.codehaus.org/), but it does not (yet) offer access to date/time, just simpler types (numeric, arrays, QNames etc). There is a request to support javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar.

Alas, not many do. However, it you are using specific package (like XOM or JDOM etc), it might not be a bad idea to ask this question on their user list.