# How parse this 2009-05-12T13:40:00Z to java date

Tags: java, parsing, date

what's the best way to parse this string 2009-05-12T13:40:00Z to a valid java date?
I'm not sure for what "T" and "Z" stands for - i guess Z means zulu?

Thanks,
Joo

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/909022/331052

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format string you have is a UTC date/time in the ISO 8601 format. The format is simply the date, a T separator and the UTC time (or zulu time).

`java.text.SimpleDateFormatter` should perform all the parsing you need.

Comment: It fails without recognizing the 'T' format symbol. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'T'

Answer (score 0):

Note that the patter has some special handling for internal static values like 'T':

See the answer here [Illegal pattern character 'T' when parsing a date string to java.util.Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597083/illegal-pattern-character-t-when-parsing-a-date-string-to-java-date)