# How do I convert 2010-12-15T16:26:49.841-08:00 to a GregorianCalendar in Java?

Tags: java, parsing, datetime, iso8601, gregorian-calendar

I have a string date "2010-12-15T16:26:49.841-08:00" and I need to convert it to a GregorianCalendar in Java.  How do you do this?

---

Solution from Jesper's answer

Code for the solution using joda time:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ").withOffsetParsed();
DateTime date = formatter.parseDateTime("2010-12-15T16:26:49.841-08:00");
```

Comment: FYI that format is the format of the [XML dataTime type](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dateTime). Conversions should exist in any decent XML API (and elsewhere)

Comment: Actually, this is ISO 8601 I think... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Comment: @Andrew White XML dateTime is mostly a specific subset of 8601 -- namely `'-'? yyyy '-' mm '-' dd 'T' hh ':' mm ':' ss ('.' s+)? (zzzzzz)?`.

Comment: I think this question has been asked quite a number of times on SO. Hey, and look below -- our first "Use JodaTime" answer...

Comment: @andersoj:  Isn't it interesting that questions with easily memorized answers are rarely flagged as duplicates.  Must have something to do with accumulating points.

Comment: @Gilbert Le Blanc: Agreed, and I'm sort of amazed that the community hasn't come up with a better way of focusing in and highlighting FAQ type questions in a single SO question.  This topic (date/time handling in Java) is a great example -- just poke around at the related tags, and you'll see all sorts of overlapping questions just begging for a unifying question/answer (and closing/redirecting all the rest).  Accumulating points by any means necessary?  Perish the thought.

Comment: @andersoj: hahaha, you're such a sissy getting all worked up over this.  you don't even provide any help. your comments are worthless and you posted twice about it.  so lame, try and get a life

Comment: Duplicate: [What's the best way to parse an XML dateTime in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/909022/642706)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the standard `SimpleDateFormat` class cannot handle [ISO 8601 format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) very well. Specifically, it cannot handle the `:` that is in the timezone offset at the end.

What you can do is manually remove the `:` from the timezone offset, so that you get a string that looks like this:

```
2010-12-15T16:26:49.841-0800
```

(note that the timezone offset is `-0800` instead of `-08:00`). Then you can parse it with `SimpleDateFormat` with the format `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ`.

But it is better to use the popular [Joda-Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) library to handle times and dates; it is much better than the standard Java API date and calendar classes and handles ISO 8601 format properly.

Comment: Note for future readers - with Java 7, you can use the "Z" specifier which corresponds to the ISO-8601 format.

Answer (score 1):

Use SimpleDateFormat, see javadocs here:

- http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Then convert the Date to Calendar. Take a look at plenty of examples here:

- http://pleac.sourceforge.net/pleac_java/datesandtimes.html

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat` doesn't support ISO 8601 format properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this piece of code

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter =
    DateTimeFormat.forPattern("your pattern").withOffsetParsed();
DateTime dateTime = formatter.parseDateTime("your input");
GregorianCalendar cal = dateTime.toGregorianCalendar();
```

This will defnitely give you the Gregorian Calender Object

Comment: You might want to mention that you are using Joda time classes here, not standard Java API classes.

Answer (score 0):

```
 String dateTimeString="2010-12-15T16:26:49.841-08:00"; 

 SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");

 DateTime dateTime = formatter.parseDateTime(dateTimeString);

 GregorianCalendar cal = dateTime.toGregorianCalendar();
```

Comment: Did you try this out? It doesn't even compile. You might want to mention that you are using Joda time classes.

Answer (score 0):

The other Answers are correct but now outdated. They use troublesome old classes now supplanted by the java.time framework.

## Using java.time

The input string happens to comply with [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard formatting. So no need to specify a formatting pattern as the java.time classes use ISO 8601 by default when parsing/generating strings.

The input string includes an offset-from-UTC, so we parse as an `OffsetDateTime`.

```
String input = "2010-12-15T16:26:49.841-08:00" ;
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( input );
```

If you have a specific time zone in mind, rather than a mere offset-from-UTC, apply that.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Los_Angele" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = odt.atZone( zoneId );
```

## `GregorianCalendar`

You should avoid the old date-time classes such as `GregorianCalendar`. But if you must to interoperate with old code not yet updated for java.time, you can convert. Use new methods added to the old classes for conversion. For more info and a nifty diagram, see my [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36639154/642706) and [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36639155/642706).

```
Calendar cal = java.util.GregorianCalendar.from( zdt );  // Do such conversions out of java.time only if absolutely necessary.
```

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the old troublesome date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `.Calendar`, & `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`.

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations.

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to [Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)) in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as `Interval`, `YearWeek`, `YearQuarter`, and more.