# how to parse a complex string into Date in java

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to parse date in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999172/how-to-parse-date-in-java)
>   [How do I convert 2010-12-15T16:26:49.841-08:00 to a GregorianCalendar in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457108/how-do-i-convert-2010-12-15t162649-841-0800-to-a-gregoriancalendar-in-java)

Example string:

```
2009-06-04T11:17:14-07:00
```

I am not sure how to construct the formatter string for this one. Anyone can help please? Thanks! :)

Comment: what have you tried? what is the format of your example date string? what does the T mean?!

Comment: What the "-07:00" means in the date?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: It's an offset specifier from UTC.

Comment: @JonSkeet reading the link of Java 7 in your answer gave me the light. Thanks.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457108/how-do-i-convert-2010-12-15t162649-841-0800-to-a-gregoriancalendar-in-java/4459026#4459026).

Comment: @Jesper: As noted on the comment on my answer, that answer is now out of date.

Comment: to @AlexLynch  I dont know, it's a string returned from citysearch web service call.

Answer (score 4):

This looks like a perfectly normal ISO-8601 date/time to me. You should be able to parse it with either [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) using the built-in APIs, or [`DateTimeFormatter`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) in [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net), using the pattern `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX"` (SimpleDateFormat) or `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"` (`DateTimeFormatter`). Note that the "X" format symbol was only introduced into Java 7; if you need to do this in Java 6 or earlier you may need to strip the colon within the offset text (so `-07:00` would become `-0700`).

Personally I'd advise you to use Joda Time anyway - it gets round the Java version issue, and it's much nicer API in general.

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat` unfortunately [can't deal with the `:` in the timezone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457108/how-do-i-convert-2010-12-15t162649-841-0800-to-a-gregoriancalendar-in-java/4459026#4459026).

Comment: @Jesper: That answer was from December 2010, before Java 7 was released with the "Z" format specifier.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that this was changed in Java 7! Thanks.

Comment: I didn't know the change made in Java7 either. Thanks a lot for your advice! Currently i still use default Java 6. Can u help vote for my question? I think I asked a good question and learned a lot from your answer. Feel pretty upset on someone down vote my question...>.<

Comment: @nanshi: Well, you didn't show what you'd tried - how far you'd got, etc...

Comment: how do i show how far i tried? I can't search on a string ended with "-07:00" and i dont know how to describe it in english. I know how to parse it without the end string.

Comment: why people are so picky while trying to help? if so, please don't help me! i only like nice people.

Comment: @nanshi: You're asking for help. People are giving their time willingly. I view it as only polite for the person *asking* the question to put time into asking a question as well as possible. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints If you don't want me to help on future questions you ask, please say so - I'd rather not waste my time.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Jon! I was just upset about the down vote last night.