# Converting a String to Date, almost done!

Tags: java, date, paypal

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting ISO8601-compliant String to java.util.Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201925/converting-iso8601-compliant-string-to-java-util-date)

I'm trying to convert this String:

```
2011-06-07T14:08:59.697-07:00
```

To a Java Date, so far, here's what I did:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.S");
Date date1 = sdf.parse("2011-06-07T14:08:59.697", new java.text.ParsePosition(0));
```

Almost everything is good, except the most important part, the **timezone** !!
The problem with [SimpleDateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#rfc822timezone) is that it expect a TimeZone in `+/-hhmm` and mine is in `+/-hh:mm` format.

Also, and I don't know why, this works:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.S Z");
Date date1 = sdf.parse("2011-06-07T14:08:59.697 -0700", new java.text.ParsePosition(0));
```

But this does not (the space before the timezone):

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SZ");
Date date1 = sdf.parse("2011-06-07T14:08:59.697-0700", new java.text.ParsePosition(0));
```

What is the correct format to transform this date `2011-06-07T14:08:59.697-07:00` to a java date ?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/909022/whats-the-best-way-to-parse-an-xml-datetime-in-java/5732733#5732733

Comment: (I'd say it's an exact duplicate, the other question also had to deal with the problem of the colon in ISO8601 timezone)

Comment: Oups, sorry. Should I close it or flag it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That looks like the ISO 8601 standard date and time format as it is used in XML. Unfortunately, Java's `SimpleDateFormat` doesn't support that format properly, because it can't deal with the colon in the timezone.

However, the `javax.xml` package contains classes that can deal with this format.

```
String text = "2011-06-07T14:08:59.697-07:00";
XMLGregorianCalendar cal = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(text);
```

If you need it as a `java.util.Calendar` then you can call `toGregorianCalendar()` on it:

```
Calendar c2 = cal.toGregorianCalendar();
```

And ofcourse you can get a `java.util.Date` out of that:

```
Date date = c2.getTime();
```

You could also use the popular [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) library which natively supports this format (and has a much better API for dealing with dates and times than Java's standard library).

Comment: Note that since Java 7, `SimpleDateFormat` does support ISO 8601 timezones, with the `X` format character. So you could use the format: `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm.ss.SSSX`

Answer (score 3):

Java **SimpleDateFormat** doesn't support colon in the timezone information. You should use other implementation such as [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/).

Example usage:

```
String dateString = "2011-06-07T14:08:59.697-07:00";
String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ";
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(pattern);
DateTime dateTime = dtf.parseDateTime(dateString);
System.out.println(dateTime);
```

maven pom.xml dependency if needed:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>joda-time</groupId>
<artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
<version>1.6.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with `S` is that it will produce three digit milli-seconds but will not parse three digits.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
System.out.println(sdf.parse("2011-06-07T14:08:59.697-0700"));
```

prints

```
Tue Jun 07 22:08:59 BST 2011
```

It appears you need to remove the `:` in the timezone.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like DateFormat can't find the end of milliseconds and the start of timezone. **Regex to the rescue!**

This is a work around:

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.S Z");
    Date date1 = sdf.parse("2011-06-07T14:08:59.697-0700".replaceAll("(?=.{5}$)", " "));
```

The regex puts a space in and this code executes without error.