# Sort Java List by pubDate

Tags: java, android, date, sorting

I would like to sort a List of "Article" object by date.

My problem is that after sorting the list, it seems that the list is not well sorted.

Here is the code to sort the list :

```
public List<Article> getArticleList() {

    Collections.sort(articleList, new Comparator<Article>() {
        public int compare(Article o1, Article o2) {
            return o1.getPubDate().compareTo(o2.getPubDate());
        }
    });

    //Collections.reverse(articleList);

    for (Article a : articleList) {
        Log.d("RssHandler", "Date after sorting : " +a.getPubDate());
    }

    return articleList;
}
```

And here is the output :

> 06-17 14:38:39.828: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Fri, 14 Jun 2013 14:47:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.828: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Fri, 14 Jun 2013 14:58:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.833: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Fri, 14 Jun 2013 15:17:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.833: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Fri, 14 Jun 2013 15:41:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.833: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Fri, 14 Jun 2013 15:58:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.833: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Fri, 14 Jun 2013 15:59:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.833: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Fri, 14 Jun 2013 16:03:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.833: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Fri, 14 Jun 2013 16:09:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.833: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Fri, 14 Jun 2013 16:34:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.833: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Fri, 14 Jun 2013 16:41:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.833: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Fri, 14 Jun 2013 16:50:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.833: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Fri, 14 Jun 2013 16:52:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.833: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Fri, 14 Jun 2013 17:24:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.838: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Fri, 14 Jun 2013 17:37:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.838: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Fri, 14 Jun 2013 17:42:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.838: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Fri, 14 Jun 2013 17:45:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.838: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Fri, 14 Jun 2013 17:54:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.838: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Fri, 14 Jun 2013 17:56:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.838: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Fri, 14 Jun 2013 17:58:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.838: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Fri, 14 Jun 2013 18:04:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.838: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Fri, 14 Jun 2013 18:20:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.838: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Fri, 14 Jun 2013 18:25:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.838: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Fri, 14 Jun 2013 18:43:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.838: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Fri, 14 Jun 2013 18:45:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.838: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Fri, 14 Jun 2013 19:18:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.838: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Fri, 14 Jun 2013 19:20:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.838: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Fri, 14 Jun 2013 19:36:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.838: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Fri, 14 Jun 2013 19:52:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.838: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Fri, 14 Jun 2013 20:14:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.838: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Fri, 14 Jun 2013 20:27:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.838: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Fri, 14 Jun 2013 20:31:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.843: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Fri, 14 Jun 2013 20:54:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.843: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Fri, 14 Jun 2013 21:00:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.843: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Fri, 14 Jun 2013 21:20:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.843: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Fri, 14 Jun 2013 22:59:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.843: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Fri, 14 Jun 2013 23:05:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.843: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Fri, 14 Jun 2013 23:08:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.843: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Mon, 17 Jun 2013 00:43:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.843: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Mon, 17 Jun 2013 06:49:40 GMT
>   06-17 14:38:39.843: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Mon, 17 Jun 2013 07:22:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.843: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Mon, 17 Jun 2013 07:26:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.848: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Mon, 17 Jun 2013 07:33:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.848: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Mon, 17 Jun 2013 07:44:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.848: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Mon, 17 Jun 2013 07:51:16 GMT
>   06-17 14:38:39.848: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Mon, 17 Jun 2013 08:02:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.848: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Mon, 17 Jun 2013 08:02:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.848: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Mon, 17 Jun 2013 08:19:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.848: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Mon, 17 Jun 2013 08:21:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.848: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Mon, 17 Jun 2013 08:37:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.848: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Mon, 17 Jun 2013 08:39:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.848: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Mon, 17 Jun 2013 08:45:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.848: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Mon, 17 Jun 2013 08:50:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.848: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Mon, 17 Jun 2013 08:51:00 GMT
>   06-17 14:38:39.848: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Mon, 17 Jun 2013 08:59:17 GMT
>   06-17 14:38:39.848: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Mon, 17 Jun 2013 09:00:00 GMT
>   06-17 14:38:39.848: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Mon, 17 Jun 2013 09:12:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.853: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Mon, 17 Jun 2013 09:14:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.853: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Mon, 17 Jun 2013 09:30:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.853: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Mon, 17 Jun 2013 09:40:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.853: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Mon, 17 Jun 2013 09:40:00 GMT
>   06-17 14:38:39.853: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Mon, 17 Jun 2013 09:51:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.853: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Mon, 17 Jun 2013 09:52:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.853: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Mon, 17 Jun 2013 09:56:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.853: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Mon, 17 Jun 2013 10:20:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.853: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Mon, 17 Jun 2013 10:30:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.853: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Mon, 17 Jun 2013 10:35:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.853: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Mon, 17 Jun 2013 10:50:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.853: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Mon, 17 Jun 2013 10:51:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.853: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Mon, 17 Jun 2013 10:52:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.853: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Mon, 17 Jun 2013 10:56:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.853: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Mon, 17 Jun 2013 11:15:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.853: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Mon, 17 Jun 2013 11:15:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.853: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Mon, 17 Jun 2013 11:17:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.853: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Mon, 17 Jun 2013 11:30:00 GMT
>   06-17 14:38:39.853: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Mon, 17 Jun 2013 11:35:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.853: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Mon, 17 Jun 2013 11:37:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.853: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Mon, 17 Jun 2013 11:41:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.853: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Mon, 17 Jun 2013 11:46:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.853: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Mon, 17 Jun 2013 11:47:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.853: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Mon, 17 Jun 2013 11:57:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.853: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Mon, 17 Jun 2013 12:01:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.858: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Mon, 17 Jun 2013 12:18:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.858: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Mon, 17 Jun 2013 12:19:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.858: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Mon, 17 Jun 2013 12:20:00 GMT
>   06-17 14:38:39.858: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Mon, 17 Jun 2013 12:30:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.858: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Mon, 17 Jun 2013 12:32:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.858: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Mon, 17 Jun 2013 12:48:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.858: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Mon, 17 Jun 2013 13:07:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.858: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Mon, 17 Jun 2013 13:11:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.858: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Mon, 17 Jun 2013 14:14:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.858: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Mon, 17 Jun 2013 14:21:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.858: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Mon, 17 Jun 2013 14:23:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.858: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Mon, 17 Jun 2013 14:31:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.858: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sat, 15 Jun 2013 07:24:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.858: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sat, 15 Jun 2013 07:25:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.858: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sat, 15 Jun 2013 07:26:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.858: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sat, 15 Jun 2013 07:36:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.858: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sat, 15 Jun 2013 07:40:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.858: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sat, 15 Jun 2013 07:42:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.858: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sat, 15 Jun 2013 07:48:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.858: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sat, 15 Jun 2013 07:50:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.858: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sat, 15 Jun 2013 07:58:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.858: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sat, 15 Jun 2013 08:08:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.858: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sat, 15 Jun 2013 08:11:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.858: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sat, 15 Jun 2013 08:50:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.858: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sat, 15 Jun 2013 09:00:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.858: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sat, 15 Jun 2013 10:09:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.858: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sat, 15 Jun 2013 10:33:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.858: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sat, 15 Jun 2013 10:34:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.863: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sat, 15 Jun 2013 10:49:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.863: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sat, 15 Jun 2013 10:59:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.863: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sat, 15 Jun 2013 11:09:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.863: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sat, 15 Jun 2013 11:35:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.863: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sat, 15 Jun 2013 12:10:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.863: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sat, 15 Jun 2013 12:26:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.863: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sat, 15 Jun 2013 13:47:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.873: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sat, 15 Jun 2013 13:52:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.873: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sat, 15 Jun 2013 14:45:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.873: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sat, 15 Jun 2013 14:55:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.873: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sat, 15 Jun 2013 15:52:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.873: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sat, 15 Jun 2013 16:34:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.873: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sat, 15 Jun 2013 16:38:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.873: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sat, 15 Jun 2013 16:56:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.873: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sat, 15 Jun 2013 17:29:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.873: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sat, 15 Jun 2013 17:35:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.873: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sat, 15 Jun 2013 18:06:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.873: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sat, 15 Jun 2013 18:20:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.873: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sat, 15 Jun 2013 18:42:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.873: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sat, 15 Jun 2013 18:43:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.873: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sat, 15 Jun 2013 19:11:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.873: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sat, 15 Jun 2013 19:18:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.873: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sat, 15 Jun 2013 19:21:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.873: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sat, 15 Jun 2013 19:22:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.873: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sat, 15 Jun 2013 19:38:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.873: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sat, 15 Jun 2013 19:44:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.878: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sat, 15 Jun 2013 20:08:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.878: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sat, 15 Jun 2013 20:10:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.878: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sat, 15 Jun 2013 20:10:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.878: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sat, 15 Jun 2013 20:32:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.878: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sat, 15 Jun 2013 21:43:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.878: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sat, 15 Jun 2013 22:21:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.878: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sat, 15 Jun 2013 23:06:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.878: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sat, 15 Jun 2013 23:14:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.878: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sat, 15 Jun 2013 23:29:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.878: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sat, 15 Jun 2013 23:56:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.878: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sun, 16 Jun 2013 01:43:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.878: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sun, 16 Jun 2013 07:23:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.878: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sun, 16 Jun 2013 07:32:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.878: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sun, 16 Jun 2013 07:34:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.883: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sun, 16 Jun 2013 07:37:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.883: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sun, 16 Jun 2013 07:38:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.883: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sun, 16 Jun 2013 07:38:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.883: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sun, 16 Jun 2013 07:42:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.883: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sun, 16 Jun 2013 07:44:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.888: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sun, 16 Jun 2013 08:08:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.888: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sun, 16 Jun 2013 08:17:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.888: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sun, 16 Jun 2013 08:58:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.888: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sun, 16 Jun 2013 09:22:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.888: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sun, 16 Jun 2013 10:28:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.888: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sun, 16 Jun 2013 10:38:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.888: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sun, 16 Jun 2013 10:42:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.888: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sun, 16 Jun 2013 10:45:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.888: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sun, 16 Jun 2013 10:53:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.888: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sun, 16 Jun 2013 11:15:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.888: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sun, 16 Jun 2013 11:17:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.888: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sun, 16 Jun 2013 11:20:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.888: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sun, 16 Jun 2013 11:45:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.888: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sun, 16 Jun 2013 11:48:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.888: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sun, 16 Jun 2013 12:23:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.888: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sun, 16 Jun 2013 12:50:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.888: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sun, 16 Jun 2013 13:42:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.888: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sun, 16 Jun 2013 14:16:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.888: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sun, 16 Jun 2013 14:32:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.888: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sun, 16 Jun 2013 14:46:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.888: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sun, 16 Jun 2013 14:54:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.888: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sun, 16 Jun 2013 14:58:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.888: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sun, 16 Jun 2013 14:59:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.888: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sun, 16 Jun 2013 15:04:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.888: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sun, 16 Jun 2013 15:12:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.893: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sun, 16 Jun 2013 15:13:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.893: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sun, 16 Jun 2013 15:33:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.893: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sun, 16 Jun 2013 15:48:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.893: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sun, 16 Jun 2013 15:55:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.893: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sun, 16 Jun 2013 16:17:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.893: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sun, 16 Jun 2013 16:23:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.893: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sun, 16 Jun 2013 16:24:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.893: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sun, 16 Jun 2013 16:47:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.893: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sun, 16 Jun 2013 16:56:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.893: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sun, 16 Jun 2013 17:32:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.893: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sun, 16 Jun 2013 18:14:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.893: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sun, 16 Jun 2013 18:19:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.893: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sun, 16 Jun 2013 18:19:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.893: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sun, 16 Jun 2013 18:21:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.893: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sun, 16 Jun 2013 18:39:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.893: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sun, 16 Jun 2013 18:50:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.893: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sun, 16 Jun 2013 19:08:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.893: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sun, 16 Jun 2013 19:17:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.893: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sun, 16 Jun 2013 19:31:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.893: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sun, 16 Jun 2013 19:45:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.893: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sun, 16 Jun 2013 20:08:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.893: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sun, 16 Jun 2013 21:00:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.893: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sun, 16 Jun 2013 21:16:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.893: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sun, 16 Jun 2013 22:00:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.893: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sun, 16 Jun 2013 22:29:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.893: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sun, 16 Jun 2013 22:32:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.893: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sun, 16 Jun 2013 22:47:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.893: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sun, 16 Jun 2013 22:51:00 +0200
>   06-17 14:38:39.893: D/RssHandler(29941): Date after sorting : Sun, 16 Jun 2013 23:12:00 +0200

For information, the list contains elements retrieved from 2 differents RSS sources.

Comment: What is your definition of **well sorted**??

Comment: I'm guessing getPubDate() returns a string?

Comment: What does `getPubDate()` return `Date` or `String` ?

Comment: Date class has no method compareTo, however String has. You are probably returning a String represenatation of the date, as you can see the values are sorted according to alphabet.

Comment: that looks sorted to me. (F < M < Sa < Su).

Comment: Yes, in fact getPubDate return a String. It's my mistake. Is it a good solution to convert my PubDate String to a Date before store it in my list ?

Answer (score 3):

It seems that `getPubDate()` returns a String. The natural order of Strings is to sort them alphabetically, which appears to be what is happening. Looking through your log, "F" comes before "M", "M" comes before "S", and so on, so, you are indeed getting a sorted list back of the Strings.

It would be better in your `Article` class to store `Date` objects (or `Long` timestamps). These will support sorting by date, which is what I assume you are after.

Comment: Yes, getPubDate return a String. It's my mistake. What is the best solution now ? Convert pubDate to a Date before adding it to my list or use SimpleDateFormat? Do you have an example to use one of these ?

Comment: Personally I would make `Article` hold a `Date` object. So whenever you instantiate an article, make sure the `Date` is created properly. There are a lot of examples on stack (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6406470/java-simpledateformat) (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056703/simpledateformat). Basically it parses a string and turns it into a date