# How can i get data in format "YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00.0" using class Date?

Tags: java, date

How can i get data in format "YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00.0" using class Date (it's extremly important to use exactly this class)?

I tried to do everything i can think of:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
df.format(date)
```

and

```
String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S";
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
try {
Date date = format.parse("2011-01-18 00:00:00.0");
} catch (ParseException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

byt when i print date using logger i get this format "Tue Sep 30 00:00:00 MSK 1913".

Comment: A duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6406470/java-simpledateformat

Comment: Another similar post which has the answer is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12781273/what-are-the-date-formats-available-in-simpledateformat-class

Comment: How are you printing the `date` object ? It seems correct to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S");
    Date date = format.parse("2011-01-18 00:00:00.0");
    System.out.println(format.format(date));
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you want the hours, minutes, secs to be zeroes?

Or do you mean the pattern yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ?

The date class is always independent of the formatting. It only needs to be translated when you print it, like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String out = df.format(date)
System.out.println(out);
```

Or do you want to strip the time out of the date object? or something.

Answer (score 1):

You are confused by `Date.toString()` and `SimpleDateFormat.format()`

An object of `Date (java.util.Date)` has **no** format information. If you call `date.toString()`, (which is called by your logger), you got default representation of this object, you have seen what it is.

However, `SimpleDateFormat.format()` will give you a string as return value, this value will format the Date object with a pattern defined by `SimpleDateFormat`.

In your code, you first parsed the string, with certain pattern, to get the date object. If it was successful, you got the Date object, here, for this date object, you don't have any format information, even if you have defined a pattern to parse the input string. If you want to print/output (to string again) the date object, you have to use the `SimpleDateFormat.format()` method.

Answer (score 0):

I hope the below one will solve your problem when you need to do for dynamic dates.

```
Date today = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd 00:00:00");
String formattedDate = sdf.format(today);
System.out.println(formattedDate);
//Above line output (formatted String object) is 2017-12-29 00:00:00
System.out.println(format.format(formattedDate));
//Above line output(parsed Date object) is Fri Dec 29 00:00:00 IST 2017
```

For Date object you can't get the output as **yyyy-MM-dd 00:00:00**, but you will get this format in String object type.