# How to save recorder audio with current date and time format

Tags: android

```
private String getFilename() {
        String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
        File file = new File(filepath, AUDIO_RECORDER_FOLDER);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.mkdirs();
        }
        return (file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + file_exts[currentFormat]);
    }
```

i want to save my file with current date and time formate, as my recorded file is not saving with current date and time format.

Comment: You have saved your file successfully but the name of the file is not like the one you want (current date and time format) , right?

Comment: yes, i want to save my file with current date and time format.

Comment: use `SimpleDateFormat`. Here are some examples http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6406470/java-simpledateformat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing this:

```
return (file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + file_exts[currentFormat]);
```

do this:

```
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
 return (file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + timeStamp + file_exts[currentFormat]);
```

Comment: let me try this :)

Comment: Thanks a lot this is working for me and i was stuck in from many hours.

Comment: Happy to help. Please check documentation of functions before you use them.  `System.currentTimeMillis()` method returns the difference, measured in milliseconds, between the current time and midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC.