# converting GMT format String to Datetime in spring boot Java

Tags: java, date, parsing

```
My Mongo Input Source data is 2020-04-14 00:00:00.0000000 (GMT-04:00), 
Data Type String
Error: Caused by: java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '' could not be parsed at index 0
at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1949) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
```

I did:

Command.java:

```
DateTimeFormatter dateTimeformatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"); 
List<RatingTiming> response = repo.findByserviceRequestedTimestampBetween(LocalDateTime.parse(query.getStartvalue(), dateTimeformatter), LocalDateTime.parse(query.getEndvalue(), dateTimeformatter));
```

Mogorepo.java :

```
public interface RatingResponseRepository extends MongoRepository<RatingTiming, String> {
    List<RatingTiming> findByserviceRequestedTimestampBetween(LocalDateTime startDate, LocalDateTime endDate);
}
```

Json.java :

```
@JsonFormat
(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'")
@JsonDeserialize(using = DateDeserializer.class)
@JsonProperty("serviceRequestedTimestamp")
public LocalDateTime serviceRequestedTimestamp;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java String to DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18823627/java-string-to-datetime)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java SimpleDateFormat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6406470/java-simpledateformat)

Comment: *FYI:* `2020-04-14 00:00:00.0000000 (GMT-04:00)` != `2020-04-14 00:00:00.000Z` since they have different time zones. `00:00 GMT-4` is the same as `04:00 GMT+0` aka `04:00Z`.

Comment: You can get value `2020-04-14T04:00:00Z` like this: `OffsetDateTime.parse("2020-04-14 00:00:00.0000000 (GMT-04:00)", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSS (OOOO)")).toInstant()`

Comment: The format you asked for, `2020-04-14 00:00:00.000Z`, is a bit funny in that it resembles ISO 8601 without being ISO 8601. The ISO 8601 standard requires a `T` before the time part, so `2020-04-14T00:00:00.000Z`. Consider whether to prefer this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please learn that we very much prefer that you do a search before posting a question here, and if you don’t find the answer that way, in your question report what you found and spell out what you are still missing. It allows for more focused and hence better answers.

Comment: Thank you very much for quick responses.  getting error : Caused by: java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2020-04-14 00:00:00.0000000 (GMT-04:00)' could not be parsed at index 10. I tried by keeping as String datatype, 
Code in repository.java : List<RatingTiming> findByserviceRequestedTimestampBetween(String startDate, String endDate);
Code in Command.java :questedTimestampBetween(query.getStartvalue(), query.getEndvalue());

Collection_Class.java : @JsonProperty("serviceRequestedTimestamp")
public String serviceRequestedTimestamp;

Comment: contd : Calling following json script via putty unix to get output

{
 "queryname": "querying rateresponse tables by eval dates",
 "field": "serviceRequestedTimestamp",
 "datatype": "string",
 "startvalue":"2020-04-14 00:00:00.0000000 (GMT-04:00)",
 "endvalue":"2020-04-16 00:00:00.0000000 (GMT-04:00)"
}

Answer (score 1):

**Edit** after question was edited: The exception message that you get, `Text '' could not be parsed at index 0`, means that you are trying to parse an empty string into a date-time, which fails since there was expected to be text in the string. How the empty string ends up there I cannot tell from your detached snippets.

### java.time

IMHO you have put your question in the wrong way. It’s only in the simplest throw-away programs that you should want to convert a date and time from one string format to another. For any Spring Boot or other serious program you should not process dates and times as strings. You should parse them into proper datetime objects and only format them back when you need to give string output.

I recommend that you use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date and time work. To parse your source string:

```
    DateTimeFormatter inputFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE)
            .appendLiteral(' ')
            .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME)
            .appendPattern(" (OOOO)")
            .toFormatter();
    
    String inputSource = "2020-04-14 00:00:00.0000000 (GMT-04:00)";
    
    OffsetDateTime dateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(inputSource, inputFormatter);
    System.out.println(dateTime);
```

Output so far:

> 2020-04-14T00:00-04:00

It’s a bit longish. We could have created a `DateTimeFormatter` directly from a format pattern string. The advantages of using the builder include:

- We are reusing two built-in formatters rather than building everything from scratch.
- `ISO_LOCAL_TIME` accepts a variable number of decimals on the seconds, so we are getting a more flexible formatter.

To format the date and time for output I am assuming (1) that you really wanted ISO 8601 format output since your example string resembles well, and (2) that you wanted the same point in time.

```
    String formattedDateTime = dateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT);
    System.out.println(formattedDateTime);
```

> 2020-04-14T04:00:00Z

The time has been changed to 04:00 UTC, the trailing `Z` that you asked for meaning UTC. This is correct: when it’s 4 AM UTC, it’s only 00:00 (midnight) in a time zone at offset GMT-04:00 where the source string came from. You asked for three decimals on the seconds, but in ISO 8601 the decimals are optional when they are zero, so here they are not printed. If you need the string for data exchange with a system that requires ISO 8601, you’re set.

If you wanted the same wall-clock time, 00:00, even though it’s a different time zone, you can have that too:

```
    String formattedDateTime = dateTime.withOffsetSameLocal(ZoneOffset.UTC)
            .format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT);
```

> 2020-04-14T00:00:00Z

If you were serious about wanting the exact format that you mentioned, even though it disagrees with ISO 8601, use a home-made formatter:

```
    DateTimeFormatter targetFormatter
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSX");
    String formattedDateTime = dateTime.withOffsetSameLocal(ZoneOffset.UTC)
            .format(targetFormatter);
```

> 2020-04-14 00:00:00.000Z

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Comment: Thank you for you help and time. One of the above option is what I want but I am still getting the same error. I think issue is where I am passing input value. So my source date is  STRING : 2020-04-14 09:10:57.0851800 (GMT-04:00) and expected datetime that will go with teradata driver schedule : select ((VLUTN_START_DTM (format 'yyyy-mm-dd')) (varchar(10))) || 'T' || ((VLUTN_START_DTM (format 'hh:mi:ss.s(3)')) (varchar(12))) || 'Z' (title ''), ((VLUTN_END_DTM (format 'yyyy-mm-dd')) (varchar(10))) || 'T' || ((VLUTN_END_DTM (format 'hh:mi:ss.s(3)')) (varchar(12))) || 'Z' (title '') (title '')

Comment: cntd: I tried changing teradata dateformat to GMT-04:00 format but not working. For now, I was calling json script in unix: "queryname": "querying mongo source",
 "field": "serviceRequestedTimestamp",
 "datatype": "string",
 "startvalue":"2020-04-14 00:00:00.0000000 (GMT-04:00)",
 "endvalue":"2020-04-15 00:00:00.0000000 (GMT-04:00)". Getting error :

Comment: Not knowing Teradata I don’t think I can add much. Beware of hardcofing `Z` as a literal, though, it’s an offset of 0 from UTC, so if your date and time are not in UTC, you will get wring results.

Comment: error: Caused by: java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2020-04-14 00:00:00.00  00000 (GMT-04:00)' could not be parsed at index 10at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.j                                                                             
        at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1851)                                                                              java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(LocalDateTime.java:492)com.lmig.grm.us.dae.command.RateResponseCommand.run(RateResponseComma

Comment: My Java code as per suggestion above : mongo repository.java : public interface RatingResponseRepository extends MongoRepository<RatingTiming, String> {

 List<RatingTiming> findByserviceRequestedTimestampBetween(OffsetDateTime startDate, OffsetDateTime endDate);
}
Collection.java: @JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")
@JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateTimeDeserializer.class)
@JsonProperty("serviceRequestedTimestamp")
public LocalDateTime serviceRequestedTimestamp;

Comment: App.java : public class App {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
     SpringApplication.run(App.class, args); 
 Command.java: DateTimeFormatter dateTimeformatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder() .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE).appendLiteral(''.append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME).appendPattern(" (OOOO)").toFormatter();
  List<RatingTiming> response = repo.findByserviceRequestedTimestampBetween(OffsetDateTime.parse(query.getStartvalue(),dateTimeformatter),OffsetDateTime.parse(query.getEndvalue(),dateTimeformatter));

Comment: You code is unreadable in the comments. You may either add it in the question or ask a new question.

Comment: okay, I will create a new question. I appreciate your help. Thank you!

Comment: I have updated main question. Could someone please guide me. Thank you in advance!

Comment: There isn’t much I can tell you, @Bsr, I have added a short paragraph at the start of the answer.

Comment: @Ole.V.V, thank you for your guidance. I was trying what you have given above, regarding :  String formattedDateTime = dateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT);
    System.out.println(formattedDateTime); It will give output 2020-04-14T04:00:00Z which is what i am looking to convert string 2020-04-14 00:00:00.0000000 (GMT-04:00) source.
Are we supposed to use dateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT); with pattern   append OOO pattern mentioned above.

Comment: I’m afraid I didn’t get the question? Aren’t you saying that my code is giving you what you want?

Comment: I mean in an example that you have posted above : 2020-04-14T00:00:00Z is what I want on my output. You have used String formattedDateTime = dateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT); Are you using this with something  before this to convert string (2020-04-14 00:00:00.0000000 (GMT-04:00))to datetime?

Comment: Yes, it’s in the first code snippet of the answer. You may simply concatenate the two snippets.