# Parse datetime string gives error on index 21

Tags: java, datetime

I have this datestring:

```
2011-11-01T13:00:00.000
```

and I don't seem to get that one parsed no matter 
if I try `SimpleDateformat` or the [`DateTimeformatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)

My last try is this one:

```
LocalDateTime datetime = LocalDateTime.parse(
  deliverydate,
  DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.S"));
```

But that gives me an **error on index 21**. Do I simply need to substring that datestring since I actually only care about the date and not the time?

Comment: have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597083/illegal-pattern-character-t-when-parsing-a-date-string-to-java-util-date

Comment: @elwis you want only `Date` ?

Comment: Try adding the ( ' ) around the T.

Comment: Check out the following link i hope it solves your problem.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6279647/converting-a-string-to-date-almost-done

Comment: @A.Wali: The `T` is already quoted - check the pattern.

Comment: @AimalKhan: That's talking about a different format using a different API...

Comment: @piyushj: That's not the problem the OP is seeing, and the `T` is already quoted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've specified *one* digit of subsecond precision - but you've got three. Use `SSS` and it's fine:

```
String text = "2011-11-01T13:00:00.000";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
LocalDateTime datetime = LocalDateTime.parse(text, formatter);
```

Also note how much more readable the code is when you separate out "creating the formatter" from "parsing the value".

Unlike `SimpleDateFormat`, `DateTimeFormatter` is immutable and thread-safe, so if you need to use this more than once I'd suggest extracting it to a static final field:

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter DELIVERY_DATE_FORMATTER =
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS", Locale.ROOT);
```

Comment: Oh that did the trick of course, i blame it on lack of coffee and too much .NET lately. thank you

Answer (score 2):

Java 7/8 is [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) compliant

The best solution for Java 7 ( see @Jon post for Java 8 )

```
    DateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
    String string1 = "2016-06-21T12:08:56.235";
    Date result1 = df1.parse(string1);
```

You can find more examples in section Examples at [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) javadoc.

Comment: The OP is using the `java.time` API, and there's no reason to take the retrograde step of going back to `java.util.*` here - it's just a matter of fixing the format pattern.

Comment: Not agree, he asked about SimpleDateformat or the DateTimeformatter

Comment: True, but given that they *can* use `java.time` and their problematic code can be fixed very easily to keep using it, I don't think it's a good idea to suggest they go back to the truly awful `java.util.Date` API. (Additionally, your answer doesn't explain the change at all - it's *just* three lines of code. Code-only answers are rarely as helpful as they could be.)

Comment: what about Java 7 ? In a native way, 'java.time' is only available for Java 8, isn't it ?

Comment: Yes, but the OP is clearly able to use it, given that they're provided an example using it. It's one thing to use the crufty API if someone *has* to, but when they don't have to, I don't think it's a good idea to provide an answer bringing them back to it.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Joda-Time have you used?

I've tried with most recent - `joda-time:joda-time:2.9.4` and below code works without any patterns:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

public class Main {

    static final String DATE_TIME = "2011-11-01T12:34:56.789";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(DATE_TIME);
        System.out.println(dateTime.toString());
    }
}
```

Sample breakpoint:

[image]

### Edit 1

After [Jon's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) comment I've tested above issue without `joda-time` (in pure Java 8) and also works perfectly.

Code:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

public class Main {

    static final String DATE_TIME = "2011-11-01T12:34:56.789";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(DATE_TIME);
        System.out.println(dateTime.toString());
    }
}
```

Sample breakpoint:

[image]

Comment: They're not using Joda Time - they're using the Java 8 `java.time` API.

Comment: @JonSkeet - both works without any formatters in Java 8 in this case. ;)