# SimpleDateFormat ParseException: Unparseable date Error

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat

I'm parsing this date format from XML:=> "**2011-12-06T07:41:14.016+00:00**", and I'm getting this error:

- **W/System.err(574): java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date:
  "2011-12-06T07:41:14.016+00:00"**

I'm certain it's the formatting statement I'm using, but I can't figure out what it SHOULD be...

Here's the statement I'm using:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSSZ:ss");
```

I get how to create a format for this part: "**2011-12-06T07:41:14**....", it's this other part :=> "**.016+00:00**" that's throwing me for a loop.

I've looked for answers here already: [Android SimpleDateFormat Page](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), and here [Oracle SimpleDateFormat Page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), but I fear I'm missing something fundamental....

Do you have any suggestions on a proper format statement for that particular date format, or pertinent resources to peruse?

Big Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should check out this related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/909022/whats-the-best-way-to-parse-an-xml-datetime-in-java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "Z" pattern matches +0000 and not +00:00 so if you remove the last ":" before you parse then it will work.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSSZ");
try {
  Date myDate = sdf.parse( "2011-12-06T07:41:14.016+00:00".replaceAll( "([0-9\\-T]+:[0-9]{2}:[0-9.+]+):([0-9]{2})", "$1$2" ) );
  System.out.println( myDate );
} catch (ParseException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Awesome! You rock! :-) 
That got me out of a sticky jam ... Big thanks!

Now is there another way to do date parsing that can better handle the variability that Date formats. I've seem some but they are clunky.

Answer (score 2):

```
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"    2001-07-04T12:08:56.235-0700
```

The :ss at the end looks incorrect

Answer (score 2):

As one of the answers in the question I linked shows, you can use

```
String string = "2011-12-06T07:41:14.016+00:00";
Calendar cal = DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime(string);
```

[What's the best way to parse an XML dateTime in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/909022/whats-the-best-way-to-parse-an-xml-datetime-in-java)