# joda-time: new DateTime(String) vs DateTime.parse(String)

Tags: java, xml, date, datetime, jodatime

Using the joda-time-2.0 version library, I was wondering, **which of this functions is better to construct from an ISO date (suposed XML `xs:dateTime` format)**: [`new DateTime(String)`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#DateTime%28java.lang.Object%29) versus [`DateTime.parse(String)`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#parse(java.lang.String)).

Because both return a different result from same value. Example:

```java
new DateTime("2012-08-16T07:22:05Z")
DateTime.parse("2012-08-16T07:22:05Z")
```

Resulting different because of the ISOChronology. First says is `ISOChronology[Europe/Paris]` and second `ISOChronology[UTC]`, although milliseconds are the same.

Also, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/909022/whats-the-best-way-to-parse-an-xml-datetime-in-java) recomends to use [`ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeNoMillis()`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/ISODateTimeFormat.html#dateTimeNoMillis%28%29), giving the same result as using the first version (`new`).

Comment: @Ilya edited question with bold. Although I thougth it was a crystal clear question...

Comment: @Sergiu Dumitriu Sorry, I didn't mention 2.0 version ^^

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The two methods use two different conversion methods: the constructor uses an instance of [InstantConverter](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/convert/InstantConverter.html), which in case of strings is a [StringConverter](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time/blob/master/src/main/java/org/joda/time/convert/StringConverter.java) and which doesn't yet support reading the timezone from the passed string, while the `parse` method uses a [DateTimeFormatter](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/ISODateTimeFormat.html) which knows how to parse the timezone.

Although both formats in theory accept an ISO datetime format, I consider that the constructor is buggy since it always uses the system timezone instead of the one specified in the string. This is inconsistent with the other possible values accepted by this constructor, which do take into account a chronology with its timezone offset. For example, this constructor will return a `DateTime` object with the UTC timezone:

```
new DateTime(DateTime.parse("2012-08-16T07:22:05Z"))
```

Comment: Is the constructor really bugged or is the timezone ignored by design?

Comment: Since the timezone isn't ignored if instead of a String we pass another JodaTime object that does have a timezone, I'd say it's a bug, but it should be confirmed by a JodaTime developer.

Comment: @datakey Yes, it's better to use `DateTime.parse`.

Comment: @Sergiu Dumitriu Ok, then I'll mail the joda-time list refering this question :) Thanks!

Comment: The behaviour of the constructor is historic and won't be changed for backwards compatibility reasons. Use the parse() method.