# How to parse this date?

Tags: java, android, parsing, date

I want to parse below date in Java,

```
2012-11-29T09:15:00.002-08:00
```

Which date format I have to use to parse it?

Comment: [Which date formats have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, this format is an XSD date format, and the simplest way to parse it (without any use of an external library) is to use [`DataTypeConverter.parseDateTime(String lexicalXSDDateTime)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html#parseDateTime%28java.lang.String%29) in the `javax.xml.bind package`. This will return you a `java.util.Calendar` object, which you can retrieve a `Date` using `Calendar.getTime()`.

Alternatively, there are solutions on SO that speaks about the same formatting, such as: What's the best way to parse an XML dateTime in Java?
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/909022/whats-the-best-way-to-parse-an-xml-datetime-in-java).

I hope this helps.

<strike>Using Date format as `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSz"`</strike>

E.g.:

```
String string = "2012-11-29T09:15:00.002-08:00";
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssSSSz", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(string);
System.out.println(date);
```

Answer (score 4):

[`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) will parse it.